# Xcode 5 - What should I change on development version of my app, before uploading to store

Tags: xcode, ios7, app-store, apple-push-notifications

My app is ready to upload. Everything works fine in development side. I wonder what I should change (about SSL or something else) before uploading to store?

Comment: does your app use SSL?

Comment: Yes. It sends push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex topic and we may not be able to answer this in once sentence.

For submission you may need a Distribution Profile from the Apple Dev Center. Depending on the functionality you're using in your app, and depending on if it's an iOS or Mac App, you may be able to use the provisioning profile Xcode has generated for you. You can set this under Build Settings - Code Signing - Provisioning Profile.

You also need to setup your app in iTunes Connect so you can submit it (this includes screenshots, App Store Category, description, etc).

To check if the submission will be successful, head over to Product - Archive, and from the screen that opens hit "Validate". This will tell you if you're missing anything.

Take a look at the App Distribution Guide for details on how to submit an app to the App Store. There's a whole chapter on Push Notifications in there too which deserve special attention: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Those technicalities aside, make sure that any NSLog and NSAssert statements that you may have used while developing are removed or not compiled before submission.